# What is the resolution of the Project Tango tablet?

Tags: hardware, google-project-tango

I am looking to start a project that requires a high resolution.

Answer (score 1):

- color image has a resolution of 1280x720
- depth sensor has a range between 0.5 to 4 meters and the depth image has a resolution of 320x180
- fisheye has 180° field of view and a resolution of 640x480